# Getting a fault when "For Each x In arr" is only one entry

Tags: vba, excel

Im using a For loop to find only new data and moving it to another sheet, but when there is only one line of input it stops and throw a fault. It stops at "For Each x in arr" and "arr" is then equal to that one input.

```
Dim arr As Variant
arr = Range("K2:K" & Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row).Value
Dim x As Variant, y As Variant, match As Boolean
For Each x In arr
    match = False
    For Each y In varr
        If x = y Then match = True
    Next y
    If Not match Then
        Sistaraden = Sheets("Sammanställning").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Sheets("Sammanställning").Range("A" & Sistaraden).Value = x
        'varr = Sheets("Sammanställning").Range("A1:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Value
    End If
Next x
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the row count first:

```
Dim arr() As Variant, lRow as Long
lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row
If lRow > 2 then
   arr = Range("K2:K" & lRow).Value
Else
   Redim arr(1 to 1, 1 to 1)
   arr(1, 1) = Range("K2").Value
End If
Dim x As Variant, y As Variant, match As Boolean
For Each x In arr
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Option Explicit` it will help you to see differences between `varr` and `arr` in your code.

Then use this line to make the array:

```
arr = Application.Transpose(Range("K2:K" & Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row))
```

The `Application.Transpose` would help you to make a 1-dimensional array out of the range. It can be looped easily.